# Problem in understanding the process of finding antiderivative.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Antiderivative or indefinite integral is the family of functions the derivative of which gives the original function.
Now, let's elaborate the process.

Suppose $F(x)$ is the derivative of the function $f(x)$ which means that **the instantaneous rate of change of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$ is $F(x)$** . $$\dfrac{d{f(x)}}{dx} = F(x)$$  Now, $$d{f(x)} = F(x)dx$$  This is the small change of $f(x)$ when there is a change of $x$ by $dx$ . Upto this point, it is correct. Then, abrubtly what books do is $$\int d{f(x)} = \int F(x)dx \implies f(x) = \int F(x)dx + C$$ . But what does this $\int$ mean? It is the counterpart of summation. So , **summing $d{f(x)}$ gives the whole change in $f(x)$ but doesn't give the function $f(x)$** . So, why did the process go like that to give the function?? It is rather giving the change in function. So, why do the books do like that??? I am confused. Please help me explaining the process.

Comment: Short answer, that's a whole lot of notation abuse and shouldn't be confused for a proof. I'm sure someone can give a reference to other discussions here on this popular topic.

Comment: An integral symbol without bounds is not a sum, it is something more "formal." Not sure what the book is doing is very helpful, for that reason. Always good to mention what book this is from, so people familiar with it can help clarify. Is it possible the book is trying to give an intuition for the fundamental theorem of calculus. The fundamental theorem is the relationship between the "indefinite integral" and the "definite integral," essentiallly.

Comment: The process is  extracted from R.D. Sharma's Mathematics. The same process has been followed by Resnick,Halliday,Walker in **Principles of Physics** to derive the equations of motion.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: Sir what does this $\int$ mean actually? Have I done anything wrong?? Please help me sir.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: Sir, I am greatly confused. If anyone helps, I will be grateful to him. I can't neglect it . In **Principles of Physics** , they have done like that....

Comment: Without knowing the context, it's hard to tell what the book is saying. I don't have access to the book. There are two meanings of $\int$, one meaning anti-derivative, another, with bounds, meaning something like the sum. Sorry I can't help any further, but without access to the book, I can't help. I wouldn't worry too much about it, because it is a physics book, not a math book.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: Thanks sir for the reply. I can only extract their deduction of the 1st eqn. as:

> We rewrite the definition of acceleration as $$dv = a.dt$$ . Now we write the indefinite integral of both sides: $$\int dv = \int a.dt$$ . Since $a$ is constant, it can be taken outside the integration. We obtain $$ \int dv = a\int dt \implies v = at + C$$

Comment: Please don't keep tagging a person who said, "I can't help you." That's obnoxious. And don't tag me in an apology. Trying to make sense of a bad book is a fool's errand.

Comment: If you know the change in a function, *and* you know the starting value of the function, then you know the function.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: That means this process gives the change plus constant. But constants do vary,sir!

Comment: If you know the starting value, that nails down the constant.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: That's what I wanted. +1 . Then $\int f(x)dx$ and $\int_a^x f(u)du$ are both indefinite intgrals; the difference being that the former needs a constant $C$ . Actually $\int f(x)dx$ is the whole change/area and if we add $C$ or the boundary condition, we get the required function,right??? Thanks!! Just asking if instead $\int_x^b f(t)dt$ is given, then can I nail the constant??

Comment: $\int_x^bf(t)\,dt=-\int_b^xf(t)\,dt$.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Oh! The clever one!! Just tell sir whether my statement above is correct or not. +1

Comment: If $F'(x)=f(x)$ then $\int f(x)\,dx=F(x)+C$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant, and $\int_a^xf(u)\,du=F(x)-F(a)$ where $F(a)$ is a non-arbitrary constant. The former is an indefinite integral; the latter, a definite integral.

Comment: So are we OK now?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Yes, your comments were intuiting; they were excellent. I have understood and you cleared my confusion. Thanks!;-D

Comment: Good. May I encourage you to write up what you now understand, and post it as answer?

Comment: You mean I will answer my own quo??? No problem!!

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: My internet connection is very weak now (2G) . I will post the ans immediately when my connection gets better.